# smtpclient.send hangs while trying to send email via office 365

Tags: c#, .net, smtp, office365, smtpclient

I am using this code to send email using office 365 exchange server.

```
var server = "smtp.office365.com";
            var port = 587;
            var username = "user@domain.com";
            var password = "password";

            var to = "test@domain.com";
            var subject = "test message";
            var body = "test message";

            var smtpClient = new SmtpClient(server, port)
            {
                UseDefaultCredentials = false,
                Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password),
                DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
                EnableSsl = true
            };

            var messsage = new MailMessage(username, to, subject, body);

            try
            {
                smtpClient.Send(messsage);
                Console.WriteLine("Mail sent completed");

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.Error.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }
```

my code simply hangs at smtpClient.Send(messsage);

I can send email using this account. The account does not have 2FA enabled. I also don't see anyone having a similar issue. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks
Tiklu

Comment: Have you tried using Fiddler to understand what is going on under the hood?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After enabling SMTP auth following this process

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/clients-and-mobile-in-exchange-online/authenticated-client-smtp-submission

we were able to solve the issue

Thanks
Tiklu

Comment: 2022, my tenant is  week old  - Nothing helps to send email from c#

Comment: Can you please some more details?

Answer (score 2):

hopefully this may help:

1. Set the Timeout of the smtpClient to a lower value and see, if you get then a timeout, or waited you for more then 1 min ?

```
smtpClient.Timeout = 100;
```

2. Startup Wireshark to analyse the smtp traffic in your network. Find out, if the server answers or not.
3. Check the firewall options of your machine
4. Check all the parameters there
5. try another mail client on the machine with the same options
6. Testtools which may possible help: https://testconnectivity.microsoft.com/tests/o365
7. try telnet https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/Exchange/mail-flow/test-smtp-with-telnet?view=exchserver-2019

Comment: I am already using outlook and that works perfectly. But as I know outlook uses a different protocol than smtp to connect to exchange server. I will surely change the timeout and check. BTW I have also checked it from an online smtp checker service and got a timeout error. Does it have something to do with exchange server settings?

Comment: that could be that other online services will be blocked by office369,
try it with a bit more low level: telnet

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/Exchange/mail-flow/test-smtp-with-telnet?view=exchserver-2019

YOu need something, that you can execute in a short on different machines in different network envirement to check, if its a firewall thing or what ever.

If telnet throws an error, mostly its more usefull then the output of outlook or other big uis.

Comment: Normally Outlook checks the account settings, using the domain acount and setup everything automaticlly. May be, you can see there in the settings, what is different to yours and try a bit around

Comment: MS has also some new test tools:
https://testconnectivity.microsoft.com/tests/o365
may be this will help you to find out the issue:
https://testconnectivity.microsoft.com/tests/O365Pop/input

Comment: It does seems Microsoft by default blocks SMTP auth. I have enabled it for the account that I am using for email using the instructions from this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/clients-and-mobile-in-exchange-online/authenticated-client-smtp-submission